# How could I map an active directory server's groups to roles (OWF - Ozone Widget Framework/Spring Security)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, cas

#### Current Status

I using a CAS Server for SSO (Single Sign On).

I using Ozone Widget Framework as a CAS client.

I've setup an LDAP Server, being used for verification with Ozone Widget Framework

On the CAS Server I can authenticate with two LDAP and Active directory server.

I'm using an Spring version 3.0.5 and Spring Security version 3.0.2.

#### Problems

I can't perform similar functionalities to the LDAP Server with an Active directory Server on Spring Security.

The active directory server is completely pre-configured.

I can't use more than 1 LDAP/AD service at once.

I've searched Google for '**mapping LDAP/AD groups to Spring Security roles**'
every result leads programming a Java Class

I can't find a valid method of role mapping without custom code.

In terms of the OWF Server, I found a number of mapping classes 'MapBaseAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper' and
 'SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper' that theoretically provide the required functionality (LDAP/AD groups mapped
to roles) the only problem is both classes implement interface 'Attributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper' and 'LdapUserDetailsService'
 
        requires a mapper interface type 'UserDetailsContextMapper'.

When using 'CAS Authentication Provider' (with 'ProviderManager' or 'authentication-provider' tag (research results)) the 'Authentication Manager' doesn't perpetuate to next 'CAS Authentication Provider'.

#### Examples (Interesting search results)

[opennms](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Spring_Security_and_LDAP)

```
<beans:bean id="UserGroupLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.opennms.web.springframework.security.UserGroupLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg value="OU=SomeDept,OU=SomeOrgUnit"/>
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
        <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}" />
        <beans:property name="groupToRoleMap">
          <beans:map>
            <beans:entry>
              <beans:key><beans:value>myusersgroup</beans:value></beans:key>
              <beans:list>
                <beans:value>ROLE_USER</beans:value>
              </beans:list>
            </beans:entry>
            <beans:entry>
              <beans:key><beans:value>myadminsgroup</beans:value></beans:key>
              <beans:list>
                <beans:value>ROLE_ADMIN</beans:value>
                <beans:value>ROLE_USER</beans:value>
              </beans:list>
            </beans:entry>
          </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>
```

[Handling roles when authenticated to active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835818/handling-roles-when-authenticated-to-active-directory-with-spring-security-3-1)

#### Requests

I would like use Spring Security default classes to configure the following: -

Map LDAP/AD groups to Spring Security roles using only XML configuration (note: no custom code, such Java Class).

Verify if the above is possible or not (with unquestionable evidence).

I would like to know if 'MapBaseAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper' or 'SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper' can be configured with an Official Spring LDAP/AD library to achieve the first request.

Finally use 2 or more CAS Authentication Providers