# Configure ldap for authorizing users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, openldap

In my current project I need to authenticate and authorize users via Spring security.

Our directory is LDAP.

I have basic ldap knowledge.

I am trying to understand how in the ldap side I suppose to manage and create users in order to provide them roles and permissions to be used in my Spring security app.

Any ref/tutorials/small explanation would be greatly welcome.

thanks,
ray.

Comment: isn't the Spring documentation on this subject enough http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html? It seems pretty detailed.

Comment: Only for the spring side. I need to configure the LDAP side with the right attributes.

Comment: ah I see! so you want to know how the server structure should look like? something like this: http://krams915.blogspot.jp/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html? It's a bit dated but looks ok!

Comment: Yes.. But how you are going to set permissions? for example ROLE_ADMIN user with name "johns" able to access(has permission) to specific resource of a page

Comment: hm well you don't add *that* to the LDAP server, if I understood the question correctly. In the LDAP you just persist user's data, which might include his role. The settings that describe which role can access a given resource (i.e. page) are kept in spring config files.

Comment: If for example I want to set that the user with name "Johns" has ROLE_USER and has the 'permission' to read-mails but user with Name "David" has ROLE_USER but doesn thave permission to read mails. I can set that information in LDAP cant I? thanks.

Comment: yes of course! In LDAP you have a set of granted authorities, you can map those to your spring roles (ROLE_USER) etc. using a UserDetailContextMapper as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835818/handling-roles-when-authenticated-to-active-directory-with-spring-security-3-1. You do not really need to prepare your LDAP in a special way for Spring, I think. That wouldn't be very useful if Spring required that.

Comment: I still didnt understand where in the ldap server I set the granted authorities of a specific user. As I said let's say user named "John" which is belong to group ROLE_USERS will be able to 'delete mails'

Comment: Hope you get me. I guess what I was asking is how to set permissions/tasks for specific users

Comment: You're asking a very broad question about how to *use* and *define* your LDAP service. It's not a programming question. Try serverfault.com, but beforehand I suggest you read more about what LDAP actually is, and how it used at a design level.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this out [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835818/handling-roles-when-authenticated-to-active-directory-with-spring-security-3-1) where is explained that:

> The roles in the beans.xml must be an exact match of the CN (common name) of the memberOf value attribute. 
>   With one good example.

Also this two examples [MVC + LDAP](http://krams915.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html) about the structure of beans.xml in relation with LDAP config.
This links is based on [MVC + InMemory Authentication](http://krams915.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-simple-user.html) where is described the way to code a custom simple login for Spring. This way you can adapt the code in MVC + LDAP example.

Hope this help.

Comment: You should summarize linked content in your answer so that it remains useful if the linked content changes or becomes unreachable.